# Rect Post request

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, post

I am creating project in React /Django Rest Framework and I want to send Post request. My problem is that I am always sending string and I should send list of int.

My component look like this

```
const NewLecture = (props) => {
    const[ lecture, setLecture] = useState({
        title:'',
        programs: [],
    })

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const history = useHistory()
    // console.log('this is history:', history)
    const program_id = props.match.params.id;

    //event handlers
    const newLectureHandler = (event) => {
    const{name, value}= event.target
    setLecture({
        ...lecture, 
        [name]:value
    })
    };



    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mounting in NewLecture');
        dispatch(LecturesActions())
        dispatch(GetPrograms())
    }, [])


    const handleSubmit = e =>{
            e.preventDefault()
            props.close()
            dispatch(sendLecture(lecture, program_id,  history))
      
    }

    const stringtoArray = (arg)=> {
       console.log('this is arg', [arg]);
        return [arg]
    }

    return (
       
            <NewGradeStyled>
                <div className="new-grade-style">
                    <h1>Create New Lecture</h1>
                    <form >
                        <div className="form-grade">
                            <label htmlFor="title">Lecture Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title"  onChange={newLectureHandler}/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-grade">
                            <label htmlFor="programs">Program</label>
                            {/* <input type="number" name="programs" onChange={newLectureHandler}/> */}
                            <select name="programs" onChange={newLectureHandler}>
                                <option >  </option>
                                {props.data ? <option value={props.data.id}>{props.data.name}</option> : ''}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div className="btn-group">
                            <button className="save" onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
                            <button onClick={props.close}>Cancle</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </NewGradeStyled>
    )
}

export default withRouter(NewLecture)
```

and this is my action

```
export const sendLecture = (lecture) => (dispatch, getState) => { 
   const{title, programs} = lecture
    const token = getState().token
    const config = {
    body: JSON.stringify(lecture),
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify({title, programs})
  };
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/backend/api/lectures/new/`, config) 
    .then((res) => res.json())  
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log('Post lecture action', data)
        dispatch({type: 'GET_LECTURE_DATA', payload: data})
    });          
}
```

I expect to get this from JSON

```
{
"title":"some string"
"programs":[1] 
}
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
lecture_data:[],
}

export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "GET_LECTURE_DATA": {
        const lecture_data = action.payload;
        return { ...state, lecture_data };
      }
 default:
        return state;
}
}
```

If I send it as input type= "number" result is always the same I get error "Expected a list of items but got type "str"."
I don´t kow how I should change it. Do you have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```js
    const config = {
        body: JSON.stringify(lecture),
        method: "POST",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({ title, programs })
    };
```

you set the body property twice. Is that intentional?
You write the api expects a list. Did you mean to pass this  `body: JSON.stringify( [title, programs ])` Although that would send an array of objects of which the first item is title, and the second is programs. Can you clarify what the API expects? And what the structure of title and programs looks like?

Comment: I edited that part in Question it should be object and inside is title which expects string and programs which expect list of int

Comment: maybe you could try something like this: ```JSON.stringify({ "title": title, "programs": programs })```